# How to connect azure with SQL manager

Tags: mysql, azure-sql-database

How do I connect Azure with SQL management if I want to link my database with azure
Connecting to SQL Azure with SQL Management Studio

Answer (score 1):

**Steps to Connect SQL Management Studio to SQL Azure**

1. Authenticate to the Azure Portal
2. Click on SQL Databases
3. Click on Servers
4. Click on the name of the Server you wish to connect to…
5. Click on Configure…

   If not already in place, click on ‘Add to the allowed IP addresses’ to add your current IP address (or specify an address you wish to connect from) and click ‘Save’
6. Open SQL Management Studio and connect to Database services (usually comes up by default)

   Enter the fully qualified server name (.database.windows.net)
   Change to SQL Server Authentication
   Enter the login preferred (if a new database, the username you specified when yuo created the DB server)
   Enter the correct password
7. Hit the Connect button

Answer (score 0):

First consider to add the current IP address of your computer to Azure SQL Database firewall as explained on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-server-level-firewall-rule) official documentation.

Now get the connection information you need to connect to the Azure SQL database. You'll need the fully qualified server name or host name, database name, and login information for the upcoming procedures.

- Sign in to the Azure portal.
- Navigate to the SQL databases or SQL managed instances page.
- On the Overview page, review the fully qualified server name next to Server name for a single database or the fully qualified server name next to Host for a managed instance. To copy the server name or host name, hover over it and select the Copy icon.

After creating the firewall rule and get the server information, the steps to connect to an Azure SQL Database are the following:

1.Open SSMS. The Connect to Server dialog box appears.
2.Enter the server information as shown in the following image:

[image]

3.Select Options in the Connect to Server dialog box. In the Connect to database drop-down menu, select your database.

[image]

4.Select Connect. The Object Explorer window opens.

5.To view the database's objects, expand Databases and then expand your database.

[image]

For a detailed step-by-step tutorial please read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-ssms) documentation.